# Android forcefully turning off speaker phone for outgoing call

Tags: java, android, error-handling, system-error, speakerphone

I am trying to make an outgoing call in speaker phone turned on programaticaly but none of the answers in the blog responds well. I tried each and every method that is available in the blog but what i figured is the android itself is forcefully turning off the speakerphone for outgoing call
I have shared the screen shot of the logcat.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue
Thanks.
I have also put a delay for 1sec and tried turning on but again the system turns off the speakerphone
I am testing on Redmi4a Naugat API25
[Log cat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAYgz.png)

Comment: @molokoka can u please help me to come out of this problem? I have read your previous question regarding this issue.I am really struck

Comment: @Eipipuz can u please suggest the solution?